# Smallest and largest magnitude root of a polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, polynomials, roots

Suppose that we have a polynomial with real coefficients like

$P(x)=a_n x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$.

Is there a way to write another polynomial whose largest magnitude root is equal to the smallest magnitude root of $P(x)$.

I mean, I am looking for a kind of transformation to give me another polynomial, say $Q(x)$, which has its largest magnitude root the same as the smallest magnitude root of $P(x)$.

**We do not want to calculate the roots of $P(x)$**. **We want to do the job by only knowing the coefficients of $P(x)$.**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: $x^{n}P(\frac 1  x)$ (assuming that $a_0 \neq 0, a_n \neq 0$).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was thinking about proposing P(1/x), but your answer is complete and beautiful.

Comment: Let $P(x)=x^2-5x+6$, then roots are $2$ and $3$, smallest root is $2$. $x^2 P(\frac{1}{x})=6x^2-5x+1$, roots are $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{3}$, largest root is $\frac{1}{2}$, not $2$.

Comment: I think in geetha290krm's method we should invert the answer.